# How to reinitialize an object in C# at the same memory location in terms of C++ (or is it done automatically)?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, cil

In C++ I used constructions like

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestStaticPointer.h"

MyClass* MyClass::myStaticPointer;

int main()
{
    ProgrammStart();

    return 0;
}

void ProgrammStart()
{
    MyClass::myStaticPointer = new MyClass();
}

void SomeProgrammPlace()
{
    *MyClass::myStaticPointer = MyClass();
}
```

So that I allocated memory just once in ProgrammStart() and then I used the same memory location to reinitialize my static pointer (without reallocating by 'new'), I just used construction "= MyClass();".

How can I do this in C#? Does the IL take all the work about allocations? Does 'new' always mean a 'new' memory location (not the same place in memory) in terms of C++?

Comment: I think its not guaranteed but if there is a chance, it could be higher if new is in a tight loop.

Comment: Memory management is handled automatically, when you do a `new`, you will probably not get the same memory location because the memory for the other object is not freed immediately. Is there a reason you want to do this, or are you just concerned about memory usage?

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I'm just concerned about memory usage but I also want to know more about .net internal memory management

Comment: You don't ever do that in C#. C# has a very different memory model than C++. Learn the C# memory model. Start by not thinking about objects as having a memory location. Objects do not have a fixed location in C#; they can move around at the whim of the memory manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you haven't re-initialized anything.  What you've done here is *assignment*.  You created a new `MyClass` object and modified the state of the existing `MyClass` object to be the same as the new one by calling its assignment operator.

The same thing will happen when you assign to a `struct` in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStruct mc = new MyStruct(10);

        // Will print 10
        Console.WriteLine(mc.i);
        unsafe
        {
            MyStruct* pmc = &mc;
            // Will print the address of mc
            Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)pmc);
        }

        // Assign to mc
        mc = new MyStruct(20);

        // Will print 20; mc was modified
        Console.WriteLine(mc.i);
        unsafe
        {
            MyStruct* p = &mc;
            // Will print the same address as above.
            // mc was modified in place
            // because structs have value semantics
            Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)p);
        }
    }
}

struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int i;
}
```

Comment: This "unsafe" code pieces give me a sense of doing something illegal :D Thank you, those things that you wrote are of those that I expected to receive as an answer, Is there any "complete guide" through the "unsafe" part of the language? I have read and accomplished the "C# Beginning 2010-2015" books by Karli Watson

Comment: The `unsafe` blocks are just there to demonstrate that the assignment modified `mc` in place rather than creating a new object and making `mc` a reference to it.  They're not integral to the way `struct` value semantics work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you could able to do what you are doing in C++ is that developer need to manage memory(free it, when your work is done) in C++.

But in Managed environments like Dot Net, CLR (Common language runtime) will take care of memory management(when and which memory it need to free, and it does very well.) for you.

The nearest answer to your question would be creating weak references for objects. so that you can invoke those reference whenever required in future.  be aware, the object having weak references will not be collected by *Garbage Collector in routine situation.  Weak references are used when there is heavy lifting process for creating a particular object, in those situations to avoid creating the object from scratch, weak reference will be created around that object. before recollecting you WR, you also need to check whether the object does exist and not GC collected (some corner situation like low memory.)

Weak references should be used very carefully otherwise they will make overhead instead of solving your problem. The best suggestion in Dot Net world is to not do memory management by yourself and let GC handle it. Though, there are some best practices one need to follow to make GC life easier.

If you wanted to know more about memory management in Dot Net, you could refer [Under the Hood of .NET Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CXVTUJ6)

*Garbage Collector - Manage environment have something called Garbage collector who would take care of memory management, allocating, releasing memory at best possible time.